# Bit masking in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I have a byte (from some other vendor) where the potential bit masks are as follows:

value1 = 0x01
value2 = 0x02
value3 = 0x03
value4 = 0x04
value5 = 0x05
value6 = 0x06
value7 = 0x40
value8 = 0x80

I can count on ONE of value1 through value6 being present.  And then value7 may or may not be set.  value8 may or may not be set.

So this is legal: value2 | value7 | value8
This is not legal: value1 | value3 | value7

I need to figure out whether value 7 is set, value8 is set, and what the remaining value is.

I have the following python code.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
value1 = 0x01
value2 = 0x02
value3 = 0x03
value4 = 0x04
value5 = 0x05
value6 = 0x06
value7 = 0x40
value8 = 0x80

def format_byte_as_bits(value):
    return format(value,'b').zfill(8)

def mask_bits_on_byte(byte,mask):
    inverse_of_mask = mask ^ 0b11111111
    return byte & inverse_of_mask

def parse_byte(byte):

    value7_set = byte & value7 == value7
    value8_set = byte & value8 == value8
    byte = mask_bits_on_byte(byte,value7)
    byte = mask_bits_on_byte(byte,value8)
    base_value = byte
    return value7_set,value8_set,base_value

# Example 1
byte = value3 | value7
value7_set,value8_set,base_value = parse_byte(byte)
print("base_value = "+str(base_value))
print("value7_set = "+str(value7_set))
print("value8_set = "+str(value8_set))
print()

# Output:
# base_value = 3
# value7_set = True
# value8_set = False

# Example 2
byte = value5
value7_set,value8_set,base_value = parse_byte(byte)
print("base_value = "+str(base_value))
print("value7_set = "+str(value7_set))
print("value8_set = "+str(value8_set))
print()

# Output:
# base_value = 5
# value7_set = False
# value8_set = False

# Example 3
byte = value1 | value7 | value8
value7_set,value8_set,base_value = parse_byte(byte)
print("base_value = "+str(base_value))
print("value7_set = "+str(value7_set))
print("value8_set = "+str(value8_set))

# Output:
# base_value = 1
# value7_set = True
# value8_set = True
```

EDIT - I LOVE stackoverflow.  So many useful answers, so quickly!  You guys are awesome!  Wish I could mark all the answers.  But I'll at least give everyone an up vote!

EDIT2 - Based on the answers below, the code is simplified to the following:

```
value1 = 0x01
value2 = 0x02
value3 = 0x03
value4 = 0x04
value5 = 0x05
value6 = 0x06
value7 = 0x40
value8 = 0x80

def parse_byte(byte):
    return byte & value7, byte & 0x80, byte & 7

# Example 1
byte = value3 | value7
value7_set,value8_set,base_value = parse_byte(byte)
print("base_value = "+str(base_value))
if value7_set: print("value7_set")
if value8_set: print("value8_set")
print()

# Example 2
byte = value5
value7_set,value8_set,base_value = parse_byte(byte)
print("base_value = "+str(base_value))
if value7_set: print("value7_set")
if value8_set: print("value8_set")
print()

# Example 3
byte = value1 | value7 | value8
value7_set,value8_set,base_value = parse_byte(byte)
print("base_value = "+str(base_value))
if value7_set: print("value7_set")
if value8_set: print("value8_set")
print()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most of your `value*` constants aren't actually bit masks, only `value7` and `value8` are.  I'd define another bit mask to extract the lower bits, so I would have three bit masks in total:

```
mask0 = 0x07
mask1 = 0x40
mask2 = 0x80
```

Now your function becomes

```
def parse_byte(byte):
    return byte & mask2, byte & mask1, byte & mask0
```

I did not convert the results to `bool` -- I don't see why this should be necessary.  When checking the returned value with `if`, it will be implicitly converted to `bool` anyway.

Also note that

```
format(value,'b').zfill(8)
```

can be simplified to

```
format(value,'08b')
```

Comment: Very succinct and I appreciate the tip on the zfill as well.  I use format(value,'b').zfill(8) all over the place, now I can just use format(value,'08b').  Thanks for your response!

Comment: As an aside, an easy way to make proper bitmasks with nice readable code is to write them like `value1 = 1 << 0`, `value2 = 1 << 1` (etc). That is, take a single bit and just change the shift. Errors are more obvious than with hex or decimal literals. If the mask needs multiple bits set, just `|` those together (eg, `value3 = (1 << 2) | (1 << 3)` instead of `value3 = 0x0c`).

Answer (score 12):

Given a value such as:

```
>>> x = 0b10001000
```

You can find out whether the top bits are set with:

```
>>> bit8 = bool(x & 0b10000000)
>>> bit7 = bool(x & 0b01000000)
```

To find which lower bit is set, use a dictionary:

```
>>> bdict = dict((1<<i, i+1) for i in range(6))
>>> bdict[x & 0b00111111]
4
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the other two functions:

```
def parse_byte(byte):
    value7_set = byte & value7 == value7
    value8_set = byte & value8 == value8
    base_value =  byte & 7
    return value7_set,value8_set,base_value
```

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't think of the byte & 7.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little verbose but perfectly fine. The only change I'd make is to simplify parse_byte:

```
def parse_byte(byte):

     value7_set = byte & value7 == value7
     value8_set = byte & value8 == value8
     base_value = mask_bits_on_byte(byte,value7 | value8)
     return value7_set,value8_set,base_value
```

Answer (score -1):

Wlio to run the byte in the register and use the instruction to get a result will also verify data and cc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).