# How to understand which bits are set to 1 in a bitarray

Tags: python, bit, flags

I am connected to a PLC with Python. This PLC, gives alarm conditions in an 8-bit representation. For example:

```
0110 0010
```

- bit 0 = lights on/off
- bit 1 = fan is on/off
- bit 2 = alarm on/off
- bit 3 = door on/off
- ...

Each bit tells different conditions.

I want to create a list of conditions and print them together, like: door is on, alarms is off , lights are off, etc..

In the above example there are three different conditions. I want to show them together, all of them can be `1` or `0`. How can I associate faults/conditions with bits?

Comment: You need to apply [`bitwise and` with a bitmask](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8508799/314291) which isolates each of the useful bit indicators, e.g. `and`ing the byte with `00000001` will isolate lights on/off. etc

Comment: `zip(list(binary_string), reversed(items))`

Comment: Note that the bitmask for bit `n` is `2**n` or `1 << n`: `0b01100010 & 1 << 2` is `0`, which tells you that the alarm is off.

Comment: See here for an example: `http://repl.it/oGQ`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi answer the question or don't, but please don't send people to off-site resources that might disappear.

Answer (score 3):

For these types of tasks I like to set up a dictionary with the bits mapped to the nice text representation. Because Python supports binary literals it's quite nicely self-documenting...

Something like:

```
status_lookup = { 0b00000001 : "Lights",
                  0b00000010 : "Fan",
                  0b00000100 : "Alarm",
                  0b00001000 : "Door"}
```

Then if you wanted a list of the currently "on" statuses:

```
bits = 0x0a # or whatever your input value was
currently_on = [status_lookup[i] for i in status_lookup if i & bits]
```

If you want to join them together in a string:

```
print("; ".join(currently_on))
```

As an alternative, if you're using Python 3.4+ you could do something similar using the new enum module:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Status(IntEnum):
    Lights = 0b00000001
    Fan = 0b00000010
    Alarm = 0b00000100
    Door = 0b00001000

bits = 0x0a
currently_on = [x for x in Status if x & bits]
```

Comment: Note that `... if i & bits]` will work, too; non-zero integers are truth-y, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways of doing it, but this will get you going:

```
s = ''
if value & 1:
    s += "lights on"
else:
    s += "lights off"

if value & 2:
    s += ", fan on"
else:
    s += ", fan off"

if value & 4:
    s += ", alarm on"
else:
    s += ", alarm off"

if value & 8:
    s += ", door on"  #?  "door open"?
else:
    s += ", door off"
```